# How to add a space in between the output when reversing the string on python?

Tags: python

This is what I have to do:

Write a Python program which accept the user's first and last name and print them in reverse order with a space between them. THE LETTERS OF THE FIRST AND LAST NAMES SHOULD ALSO BE IN REVERSE ORDER!!!!!  For example if a person enters first name is Sam and last name is Murrow then the output should be maS worruM...

-
I can't figure out how to add the space in between firstname & lastname. This is what I have so far:

```
firstname = input("What is your last name?:")
lastname = input("What's your last?: ")
print  (lastname)  +  (firstname)[::-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

In your solution you are only reversing the `firstname` string. What you can do instead is build your full string including both `firstname`, `lastname` and a space between them, and then reverse the entire string.

For example:

```
firstname = input("What is your last name?:")
lastname = input("What is your last?")
print(firstname[::-1] + " " + lastname[::-1])
```

Comment: `Sam Mullan` reverses to `maS nalluM` so the first name should still be first.

Comment: also just `(firstname + " " + lastname)` will return a string, you don't need to then convert that string to a string.

Comment: Thanks Tadhg, I misread the question. My solution above is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   firstname = input("What is your first name?:")
   lastname = input("What's your last name?: ")
   fn = firstname[::-1]
   ln = lastname[::-1]  
   print (fn,"",ln)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
first_name = input("Enter your First Name: ")
last_name = input("Enter your Last Name: ")
print(f"{first_name[::-1].strip()} {last_name[::-1].strip()}")
```

This code will prompt the user to input their First and Last names separately and then store those values in `first_name` and `last_name` variables respectively so that they can be used in the `print` statement (or for other purposes). Also it will remove extra space from input while it will print output

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach to solve this problem

```
print("Enter the name: ")
name = str(input()).split(' ')

namez = name.reverse()
for i in range(len(name)):
    print(name[i][::-1], end=" ")
```

Answer (score -1):

`print("{last} {first}".format(last=lastname[::-1], first=firstname[::-1]))`

Comment: `Sam Mullan` reverses to `maS nalluM` so the first name should still be first, also please include some explanation with your code.

Answer (score -1):

```
first_name = input("Input your First Name : ")
last_name = input("Input your Last Name : ")
print ("Hello  " + last_name + " " + first_name)
```

Comment: Your code does not reverse the last_name and first_name.